# Cleaner way of writing multiple hide show jquery functions?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

New to website development and would greatly appreciate some advice! For this app I am creating I have multiple sections appearing and disappearing on click and I just keep writing out hide(), hide(), hide(), show() for every possible button click. I know there has to be a cleaner more efficient way of writing it! Would anybody have any recommendations?

Please note (that when the button is clicked classes need to be removed as well) Not sure if that makes a big difference.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {


    var pharmaCanvas = document.getElementById('pharmaceuticals_canvas'); 
    var welcomeCanvas = document.getElementById('welcome_canvas');
    var CK_canvas = document.getElementById('pharma_CK_canvas');
    var QL_canvas = document.getElementById('pharma_QL_canvas');


    $(pharmaCanvas).hide();
    $(pharma_dashboard).hide();
    $(pharma_CK_canvas).hide();
    $(QL_canvas).hide();
    
    




$('.menuBtns').click(function(){

        //This will decrease the left menu size on click// 
        
        $("#left_menu").toggleClass("menu_decrease");
        $(".left_menu_title").toggleClass("menu_decrease_title");


});
    
    $('#pharmBtn').click(function(){
        
        //Opens up Overview, as default
        $(pharmaCanvas).fadeToggle(2000);
        
        //opens up the PHARMA Dashboard / Right Dashboard //
        $(pharma_dashboard).toggle();
        
        //Toggles the WELCOME Dashboard which is not secific to any sector's dashboard//
        $(welcome_dashboard).toggle();
        
        //The secondary menu/ dashboard menu item will turn grey //
        $("#pharma_default").addClass("selected_item_grey");
        
        //This is for the Background  color of the menu will stay when sector is selected//
        $("#pharma_left_menu").toggleClass("selected_left_menu_title");
        
        //Hide all other canvases//
        $(welcomeCanvas).hide();
        $(pharma_CK_canvas).hide();
        $(pharma_QL_canvas).hide();
        $(welcomeCanvas).hide();
    
    })
    
    //Start Dashboard Journey Here//
    
    $('#pharma_OBtn').click(function(){
    
        $(pharmaCanvas).toggle();
        $("#pharma_default").addClass("selected_item_grey");
        $("#pharma_CK").removeClass("selected_item_grey");
        
        $(pharma_CK_canvas).hide();
        $(welcomeCanvas).hide();
        
        $(pharma_QL_canvas).hide();
    
    })

    
    $('#pharma_CKBtn').click(function(){
    
        $(pharma_CK_canvas).toggle();
        $("#pharma_CK").addClass("selected_item_grey");
        $("#pharma_default").removeClass("selected_item_grey");
        $("#pharma_QL").removeClass("selected_item_grey");
        $("#left_menu").addClass("");
        
        $(pharmaCanvas).hide();
        $(pharma_QL_canvas).hide();
    
    })
    
    $('#pharma_QLBtn').click(function(){
    
        $(QL_canvas).toggle();
        $("pharma_QL").addClass("selected_item_grey");
        
        $("#pharma_default").removeClass("selected_item_grey");
        $("#pharma_CK").removeClass("selected_item_grey");
        
        
        $(pharmaCanvas).hide();
        $(pharma_CK_canvas).hide();
    
    })
  
 

});
```

```css
/* Main Section */

.main_container{

    /* 
    width:1260px;
    height: 470px;
    */
    
    

}

#canvas{
    display: inline-block;
    
}

.column_right{
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    width: 179px;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
    margin-top: -240px;
    z-index: 3;
    height: 245px;
    background-color: #f6f6fc;
}

#pharma_right_column{
    margin-top: -470px!important;

}

#wrapperForMenus{

    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

/* 
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  background: white;
}*/

/* Track 
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  
  border-radius: 10px;
}
 
 Handle 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #dbdbdb; 
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; 
  border-radius: 10px;
}

Handle on hover
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #b1b0b0; 
}

 */

/* Menus */
#left_menu{
    height: 100vh; 
    width: 200px;
    float: left; 
    background-color: #323896;
}

.main_menu_title{
    font-family: Arial Black;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-decoration: none!important;
    color: white!important;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.main_menu_subtitle{
    font-family: Arial Black;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white!important;
    text-decoration: none!important;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.left_menu_title{
    font-family: Arial Black!important;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white!important;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 35px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-top: 9px;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
    text-decoration: none!important;

    background: linear-gradient(to right, #323896 50%, #f6f6fc 50%) left;
    background-size: 200%;
    transition: .5s ease-out;
}


.left_menu_title:hover{
    background-position: right;
    color: #323896!important;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none!important;
    
}

.row_left_menu_item{

    height: 15%;
}

.menu_decrease{
    width:115px!important;
    transition: all .5s linear;
    
}

.menu_decrease_title{
    font-size: 11px!important; 
}
.menuBtns{
    text-decoration: none!important;
}

.selected_left_menu_title{
    color: #323896!important;
    background: #f6f6fc!important;

}


.dashboard_menu_title{
    font-family: Arial Black;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #323896!important;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.dashboard_menu_subtitle{
    font-family: Arial Black;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #acacac!important;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
#dashboard_menu{
    height: 100vh; 
    width: 200px;
    float:left;
    background-color: #f6f6fc;
    box-shadow: 4px 0 5px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
}

.dashboard_menu_selection{
    font-family: Arial Black;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #acacac!important;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 49px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<!-- J Query Library -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- SPServices -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">    
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.12/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css"> 
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices-2013.02a.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    
    <script src="https://sharepointtechie.sharepoint.com/sites/appnfc/SiteAssets/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  


<div class="main_container" id="welcome_container">
    <div id="wrapperForMenus">
        <div id="left_menu">
            <h1 class="main_menu_title">Sector</h1>
            <h1 class="main_menu_subtitle">Select Sector</h1>
        
            <div class="row_left_menu_item">
                <img class="left_menu_icons" src="">
                <a id="epsBtn" class="menuBtns"><h2 class="left_menu_title" id="">DONT CLICK</h2></a>
            </div>
            <div class="row_left_menu_item">
                <img class="left_menu_icons" src="">
                <a id="enterpriseBtn" class="menuBtns"><h2 class="left_menu_title" id="">DONT CLICK</h2></a>
            </div>
            <div class="row_left_menu_item">
                <img class="left_menu_icons" src="">
                <a id="consumerBtn" class="menuBtns"><h2 class="left_menu_title" id="">DONT CLICK</h2></a>
            </div>

            <div class="row_left_menu_item">
                <img class="left_menu_icons" src="">
                <a id="medBtn" class="menuBtns"><h2 class="left_menu_title" id="">DONT CLICK</h2></a>
            </div>
            <div class="row_left_menu_item">
                <img class="left_menu_icons" src="">
                <a id="pharmBtn" class="menuBtns"><h2 class="left_menu_title" id="pharma_left_menu">CLICK ME!!</h2></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="welcome_dashboard">
            <div id="dashboard_menu">
                <h1 class="dashboard_menu_title">Index</h1>
                <h1 class="dashboard_menu_subtitle">Select Option below</h1>
                
                <div class="dashboard_menu_row">
                    <h2 class="dashboard_menu_selection" style="margin-top: 100px;" >Please Select Sector to Display Options</h2>
                </div>
            
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="pharma_dashboard">
            <div id="dashboard_menu">
                <h1 class="dashboard_menu_title">BPU Index</h1>
                <h1 class="dashboard_menu_subtitle">Select Option below</h1>
                <a id="pharma_OBtn">
                    <div class="dashboard_menu_row">
                        <h2 class="dashboard_menu_selection" id="pharma_default">Overview</h2>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a id="pharma_CKBtn">
                    <div class="dashboard_menu_row">
                        <h2 class="dashboard_menu_selection" id="pharma_CK">CK</h2>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a id="pharma_TrainBtn">
                    <div class="dashboard_menu_row">
                        <h2 class="dashboard_menu_selection" id="pharma_Train">NOT ACTIVE YET</h2>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a id="pharma_TeamBtn">
                    <div class="dashboard_menu_row">
                        <h2 class="dashboard_menu_selection" id="pharma_Team">NOT ACTIVE YET</h2>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a id="pharma_QLBtn">
                    <div class="dashboard_menu_row">
                        <h2 class="dashboard_menu_selection" id="pharma_QL">QL</h2>
                    </div>
                </a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    

                    </div>
                    
                
                        
                </div>

    <div id="welcome_canvas">
            <h1> Welcome Canvas At Start </h1>
    </div>

    <div id="pharmaceuticals_canvas">                   
        <h1> default section</h1>
    </div>
            
    <div id="pharma_CK_canvas">
          <h1> hi CK </h1>
    </div>
        
            <div id="pharma_QL_canvas">
        <h1> hi QL </h1>
            </div>
        


        
        
        

        
        
        
        
        
        <!-- Main Container End -->




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use multiple targets in the selector i.e `$('#pharmaceuticals_canvas, #welcome_canvas, #etc').hide()`

Comment: Also, I see you select your data using `document.getElementById("someElementid")` and then use the selected element like this: `$(selectedElement)`. You can just directly select the elements in jQuery this way: `$("#someElementid")` (using the same selector as you would in CSS). The previous comment did use that technique but I wanted to make it more clear. Cheers

Comment: if the general pattern is, `I have a list of things, and I want to toggle one thing in the list and hide everything else`, then you can create a single function that takes the one thing you want to toggle as an argument, and hides everything else.

Comment: Why do `var pharmaCanvas = document.getElementById('pharmaceuticals_canvas'); $(pharmaCanvas).hide()` instead of just `$('#pharmaceuticals_canvas').hide()`? That's just jQuery with extra steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very likely not exactly what you're looking for, but it's an implementation of what i suggested in the comments:

```
var pharmaCanvas = document.getElementById('pharmaceuticals_canvas'); 
var welcomeCanvas = document.getElementById('welcome_canvas');
var CK_canvas = document.getElementById('pharma_CK_canvas');
var QL_canvas = document.getElementById('pharma_QL_canvas');

var elementList = [pharmaCanvas, welcomeCanvas, CK_canvas, QL_canvas, '#pharma_default', '#pharma_left_menu', '#pharma_CK'];

function toggleOrHide(toggle, list) {
  for (let element of list) {
    if (element === toggle) {
      $(element).toggle();
    } else {
      $(element).hide();
    }
  }
}


$('#pharma_OBtn').click(function(){    
    toggleOrHide(pharmaCanvas, elementList);    
})
```

It seemed like most of your functions were `toggle one element, hide all the other ones`, so if you are able to keep it consistently like that then you can create a function that does the job for you.

Comment: Can you explain the "for (let element of list) " what is the purpose of "list" ? I just want to understand the full logic and not just copy paste

Comment: the `list` is your `elementList`, as defined here: `var elementList = [pharmaCanvas, ...` . To loop over the elements of the list, you do `for ... of `

Comment: so you're looping over every element of the list, and if it matches the `toggle` element, you toggle it, otherwise you hide it.